# Angular2 - dynamic variable in html

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list which looks like this:

```
<ul *ngFor="#item of items">
<li><img src="http://something.com/[this needs to be item.id]/picture"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to the image url to be that of the id of the item. I looked at the src documentation for angular2 (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) and tried the following:

```
<img [src]="http://something.com/{{item.id}}/picture">
```

but it did not work. How can I have the image show up based on the item's id which needs to be in the url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use property binding with string literals:

```
<img [src]="'http://something.com/' + item.id + '/picture'">
```

or string interpolation property binding with `{{}}`s:

```
<img src="http://something.com/{{item.id}}/picture">
```

---

Note that `[src]="http://something.com/{{item.id}}/picture">` doesn't work because property binding with `[]` uses the syntax `[property]="template_expression"` and the [template_expression](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions) can not contain `{{}}`s.

Comment: I think 1st should appropriate, as like `ng-src` in Angular 1, where as 2nd one can form incorrect URL like `http://something.com//picture`, correct?

Comment: Thanks! It works! And thanks for explaining why my approach didn't work!

Comment: @PankajParkar, well, both forms will generate incorrect URLs if `id` is not a property of the `item`.  The first will produce `"http://something.com/undefined/picture"` and the second, `"http://something.com//picture"`.

Comment: @MarkRajcok correct.. even that could failed if you don't have `Elvis` operator in a place.. like `item?.id`

Comment: @PankajParkar, I tried, and it doesn't seem like the Elvis operator is needed here.  I didn't get any errors when I added an item to the array that didn't contain an `id` property.  I suppose this is because `item` always exists.

Comment: @MarkRajcok that why I said, `[src]` would evaluated the expression when value changes, the CD will take out that value and will put it inside `href` attribute.. I think that error can be easily reproducible with 2nd way you suggested.. I'm not fully sure about it.

Comment: @PankajParkar, oh, okay, now I see your point.  I believe both forms will result in invalid URL fetches if the `id` field is not populated when the view is rendered or updated.